# How to find selected value of upper row of a table with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table like this.
[image: table]
And the rows of that table are loop with php.
I want the option value of upper row when user click option value from next row of that table. I mean is, if I click option from row number 3, I want to get the option value of row number 2.
So, I already try like this.

```
$("select[name='service[]']").change(function(event){
        console.log("row"+$("table[name='tbl_list'] tr:last").prev().index());
});
```

But I get only `row14` every row I clicked. So, how can I get the user selected option value of upper row when I click the option from the next row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use closest to get the parent row and prev to get the previous row

```
$("select[name='service[]']").change(function(event) {
  var val = $(this).closest("tr").prev('tr').find("option:selected").val();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and how can I get right side column value of that option column of upper row?

Comment: @Cloud you refine you search to select only that element

Comment: Can you please show me sample code? Because I get wrong result, when I try.

Comment: if you provide the html structure i may help you

Comment: Thank you, now i got it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use,

```
$("select[name='service[]']").change(function(event) {
  $(this).closest("tr").prev().find("select").val();
});
```

Get the parent tr using `closest("tr")`

Get the upper tr by using `prev().`

Then get the select inside it by using the `.find("select")`